# Netmiko Login failure handling

Tags: python, netmiko

I was after some help. I'm trying to write a script to SSH to a device and if authentication failed print out a statement "Login Failed". Unfortunately the error handling doesn't seem to work and throws a error see trace below.

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm new to python.

Many Thanks
Ric

````
from netmiko import Netmiko
from getpass import getpass
from netmiko import ssh_exception
from paramiko.ssh_exception import AuthenticationException
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetmikoAuthenticationException
import sys

Netmiko(
"1.1.1.1",
username="fred",
password=getpass(),
device_type="cisco_ios",
)


try:
   net_connect = ConnectHandler(**Netmiko)
except (AuthenticationException, NetmikoAuthenticationException):
   print("Login failed")
   sys.exit()

print(net_connect.find_prompt())
net_connect.disconnect()```



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 892, in establish_connection
    self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 446, in connect
    passphrase,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 764, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 751, in _auth
    self._transport.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1509, in auth_password
    return self.auth_handler.wait_for_response(my_event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 250, in wait_for_response
    raise e
paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LoginCheck.py", line 13, in <module>
    device_type="cisco_ios",
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/ssh_dispatcher.py", line 252, in ConnectHandler
    return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 318, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 323, in _open
    self.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netmiko/base_connection.py", line 905, in establish_connection
    raise NetmikoAuthenticationException(msg)
netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoAuthenticationException: Authentication failure: unable to connect cisco_ios 1.1.1.1:22
````

Answer (score 0):

instead of printing "Login failed" in `except`, you can simply collect all the exceptions as below:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

By this way you can collect every exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

When defining your Netmiko parameters, you give `key:value` pairs for everything except the IP Address in which you only provide the 'value'. You always need to provide the 'key' for any value. Also, when defining Netmiko parameters, enclose them in curly brackets, not parentheses. You should review your import statements, they can be cleaned up. Really you should try to pay a bit more attention to detail as you write since that is quite important when scripting.

```
Netmiko{
ip: "1.1.1.1",
username: "fred",
password: getpass(),
device_type: "cisco_ios"
}
```